# "We have to wear a school uniform" or "We have to wear school uniforms"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, articles

"**We**" is a plural noun but why do people say "**We have to wear a school uniform**"?

We wear only a school uniform??

What about "**We have to wear school uniforms**"?

Also, "**We speak English with an American accent**" vs "**We speak English with American accents**"?

Answer (score 3):

**We** is plural, but it can be used to express different concepts.  There is also the issue of whether the intent is to talk about a single, standard uniform, or multiple kinds of uniforms, such as for the different seasons.

1. If there are multiple standard uniforms that are used for different occasions, seasons, etc., and you are talking generally about it, uniforms would be plural even if you were talking about only yourself: "I/we have to wear school uniforms".  Uniforms is plural because it refers to multiple types of uniforms.
2. If it is just you and just one uniform, that's another clearcut case: "I have to wear a school uniform."

From there it gets complicated and ambiguous.  If there is only one type of uniform and multiple people, you could have these kinds of scenarios:

3. You can refer to everyone at the school ("we" as in "we all").  In that case, it would be correct to say "We have to wear school uniforms".  Otherwise, it would imply that the entire student body is squeezing into a single uniform.
4. You can use "we" to refer to yourself in the context of your actions being governed by the same policies that affect everyone else at the school.  For example, someone asks you "Do you wear a school uniform?"  You might reply "We have to wear a school uniform."  "We" in this case means "I in the context of all students in the school".  If you were to say "I have to wear a school uniform" it could imply that you do, but not everyone else does.

   However, suppose you hated the uniform and the idea of being required to wear it.  If you wanted to focus on only your own situation, you might say "I have to wear a school uniform".  In this case, the context of the other students isn't relevant to your point.

Regarding the accents, this is another case where context makes a difference, but not because of "we".  "...with an American accent" modifies "speak" not "we", so the plurality of "we" is irrelevant.  Whether "accent" is singular or plural depends on how many accents you're talking about.  A couple of examples:

- You are non-American and you and some of your classmates from home were exchange students in the US for a year, during which you all acquired a little of the local accent.  You might say "We speak with an American accent."
- You are an American talking to people from somewhere else describing the range of speech patterns found throughout the US.  You might say "We speak with American accents."

Comment: In dictionary, "a/an used before singular nouns to mean all things of a particular type"   
 *A square has four sides (=all squares have four sides).*        
 *A child needs love and affection.*

Comment: @Tom, that's one use of a/an.  I'm not understanding your point.

Comment: see my answer, "We have to wear a school uniform"="We have to wear a particular type of school uniform"

Comment: @Tom, that isn't really correct.

Comment: @Tom "**We have to wear a school uniform**" means "**Each of us has to wear a school uniform**". It refers to a single school uniform for every single person in the we-group. Fixer's answer explains it all perfectly well.

Answer (score -1):

[This site says,](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/indefinite-article-and)

> "A / AN" used before singular nouns to mean all things of a particular
>   kind
>
> A square has four sides (=all squares have four sides).
>
> A child needs love and affection.

So, "**We have to wear a school uniform**"="**We have to wear a particular type of school uniform**"

Comment: What you wrote about a/an is correct as far as it goes, but that isn't the only use.  Your conclusion isn't really correct.  That would probably be more associated with "the".  It isn't obvious how you think that answers your question (unless I misunderstood the question).

Comment: @fixer1234, see this link http://www.weatherheadhigh.co.uk/page/?pid=374, "*We have to wear a school uniform that is a white shirt with blue short and black shoes.*"

Comment: that sentence is correct, and it includes a description of the uniform.  But your interpretation of a/an is incorrect.  Also, the question was about singular/plural in relation to "we".  It isn't clear how you're relating a/an to that.

Comment: @fixer1234, so, does "*We have to wear a school uniform*" mean "*We have to wear a particular type of school uniform*"?

Comment: Your link describes the endless uses of a/an.  The one relevant to the question is " used to show that you are talking about someone or something that has not been mentioned before, or that your listener does not know about" or perhaps "used to show that you are referring to a general type of person or thing and not a specific person or thing".  "A school uniform" means "a single example of something that falls in the category of school uniform".

Comment: @fixer1234, or you can check this link https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/determiners-and-quantifiers/indefinite-article-and, see the number 5

Comment: That definition is a little ambiguous and easily misunderstood.  A better way to express that meaning might be "an example that applies to all things of that kind".  The equal sign is misleading.  "A" really means "any" rather than "all".  If you start with "all men need friends", then it follows that "any man needs friends", because any man is an example of all men.  So "a man needs friends" means "any example man needs friends" because all men need friends.

Comment: Tom, I downvoted your second part of the answer because it's incorrect. Fixer's got a point. "**We have to wear a school uniform**" really refers to that "**each person (we) has to wear a school uniform in general**". So to say, a school uniform is a general thing that should be worn by each and every entity of a group *(**we** in our case)*.

Comment: Speaking about the a/an rule, the definition is correct but incomplete. In almost all cases it means **in general** but there are exceptions. Here, **a school uniform** refers to any kind of uniform that is worn to school. Each school can have their own kind.

Comment: @Tom, re: the definition that was confusing: think of the equal sign like this: it doesn't mean that the example phrase is literally equal to the explanation phrase, so "a" & "all" are interchangeable, it means that it is equivalent to the explanation phrase. Logically, it means the same because one implies the other, but they aren't literally equal. The equal sign is a kind of shorthand that isn't being used precisely in the definition.  The author was apparently trying to keep the examples concise, perhaps without realizing that the shorthand could easily be interpreted in an incorrect way.